# Bull's-eye charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

A colleague of mine needs to plot 101 bull's-eye charts.  This is not her idea.  Rather than have her slave away in Excel or God knows what making these things, I offered to do them in R; mapping a bar plot to polar coordinates to make a bull's-eye is a breeze in `ggplot2`.

I'm running into a problem, however: the data is already aggregated, so Hadley's example [here](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_polar.html) isn't working for me.  I could expand the counts out into a factor to do this, but I feel like there's a better way - some way to tell the geom_bar how to read the data.

The data looks like this:

```
    Zoo Animals Bears Polar Bears
1 Omaha      50    10           3
```

I'll be making a plot for each zoo - but that part I can manage.

and here's its `dput`:

```
structure(list(Zoo = "Omaha", Animals = "50", Bears = "10", `Polar Bears` = "3"), .Names = c("Zoo", 
"Animals", "Bears", "Polar Bears"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note: it is significant that Animals >= Bears >= Polar Bears.  Also, she's out of town, so I can't just get the raw data from her (if there was ever a big file, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this without disaggregating is to use `stat="identity"` in `geom_bar`.

It helps to have the data frame containing numeric values rather than character strings to start:

```
dat <- data.frame(Zoo = "Omaha",
               Animals = 50, Bears = 10, `Polar Bears` = 3)
```

We do need `reshape2::melt` to get the data organized properly:

```
library(reshape2)
d3 <- melt(dat,id.var=1)
```

Now create the plot (identical to the other answer):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d3, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
    geom_bar(width = 1, colour = "black",stat="identity") +
    coord_polar()
```

Comment: This seems like the most intuitive answer to me now - I do this kind of thing often in my work these days, although it's hard to remember if I even understood the concept of molten data back then. Thanks for taking the time with this old question!

Answer (score 3):

While we're waiting for a better answer, I figured I should post the (suboptimal) solution you mentioned.  `dat` is the structure included in your question.

```
d <- data.frame(animal=factor(sapply(list(dat[2:length(dat)]),
                function(x) rep(names(x),x))))
cxc <- ggplot(d, aes(x = animal)) +  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = "black") 
cxc + coord_polar()
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris!  That's very close to what I'd put together, except I had explicitly spelled out the rep() for each group.  sapply() is still like magic to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inverse.rle` to recreate the data,

```
dd = list(lengths = unlist(dat[-1]), values = names(dat)[-1])
class(dd) = "rle"
inverse.rle(dd)
```

If you have multiple Zoos (rows), you can try

```
l = plyr::dlply(dat, "Zoo", function(z)  
      structure(list(lengths = unlist(z[-1]), values = names(z)[-1]), class = "rle"))

reshape2::melt(llply(l, inverse.rle))
```

Comment: That is some very clever data wrangling - +1